# Email validation function not working properly with form button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, email-validation

I am working on my final project for my JS class. I have reached a bit of a roadblock, and was hoping for a little guidance.
I am looking to take the input (all coding needs to be done in JS) for email and validate. If the email is validated, then it should send the input to be written on a new webpage. If the the input is not valid, there should be an alert and the user should then reenter a proper email address.
This is just a portion of the project. I am creating having the user enter input information for a resume to written on the new page.

With the current state of the code, it is popping up the alert box that the email is not valid (even when it is). I have gotten it write if I take away the validation portion. However, it writes "undefined".

```
//html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lan= "en">
    <head>
        <title>WEB 115 Final Project</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <script src= "projectJS.js"></script>
            <br><br>
            <form onsubmit="validateEmail()">
                <input type="submit" value="Create Resume">
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
//JS email
var email = document.createElement("p");
email.innerText = "Enter Email Address:";
document.body.appendChild(email);
var inputEmail = document.createElement("input");
inputEmail.type = "text";
inputEmail.setAttribute("id", "email");
document.body.appendChild(inputEmail);

//email validation on click form button from html
function validateEmail(inputEmail) {
    var re = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
    var testRe = re.test(inputEmail);
    testRe;
    if (testRe != true) {
        window.alert("Invalid Email Address. Please Reenter");
    }
    else {
        var openWindow = window.open("");
        openWindow.document.write(inputEmail);
    }
}
```

If anybody would be so kind as to advise on this issue, I would be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly qualifies as a valid email address? Just want to confirm that's actually what your regex is doing.

Comment: It is testing for_@_._ Basic test. Any character and any amount for the "underscores". Ie: whoknows@whatever.com

Answer (score 1):

The issue was simply that you were passing `inputEmail` as the argument to `test()` when what you actually want to test is `inputEmail.value`. Demonstration below should work:

```js
const validateEmail = (e, inputEmail) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/.test(inputEmail.value)) {
    console.log(`${inputEmail.value} is a VALID email address :)`);
    return true;
  }
  console.log(`${inputEmail.value} is an INVALID e-mail address. Please fix!`);
  return false;
};

const init = () => {
  var email = document.createElement("p");
  email.innerText = "Enter Email Address:";
  document.body.appendChild(email);

  var inputEmail = document.createElement("input");
  inputEmail.type = "text";
  inputEmail.setAttribute("id", "email");
  document.body.appendChild(inputEmail);

  document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => validateEmail(e, inputEmail));
};


init();
```

```html
<head>
  <title>WEB 115 Final Project</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="projectJS.js"></script>
  <br><br>
  <form>
    <input type="submit" value="Create Resume">
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved your problem. Now it's working. Check it.

```js
var email = document.createElement("p");
email.innerText = "Enter Email Address:";
document.body.appendChild(email);
var inputEmail = document.createElement("input");
inputEmail.type = "text";
inputEmail.setAttribute("id", "email");
document.body.appendChild(inputEmail);

//email validation on click form button from html
function validateEmail() {
    var inputEmail = document.getElementById('email').value; //get email id
    var re = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
    var testRe = re.test(inputEmail);
    testRe;
    if (testRe != true) {
        window.alert("Invalid Email Address. Please Reenter");
    }
    else {
        var openWindow = window.open();
        openWindow.document.write(inputEmail);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lan= "en">
    <head>
        <title>WEB 115 Final Project</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <script src= "projectJS.js"></script>
            <br><br>
            <form onsubmit="validateEmail()">
                <input type="submit" value="Create Resume">
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am having the same issue as the above comment;

Comment: That solved the issue of it not following the if statement popping up the alert box. But it is not executing the else.

Comment: So it is not opening up a new webpage and writing the input

Comment: @KButler Brother, this code is working properly. It can't open a new window from stackoverflow. Because stackoverflow has blocked this permission. You can try this code on your pc or can try in this link [https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G61ZL6947UMD](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G61ZL6947UMD) . I just saved this code in the link. Give it a check.

Comment: @Shorwin Barua, for whatever reason it wasnt working for me initially. However, I have got it functioning properly now. Thank you for your kindness. +1

Comment: Welcome @kbutler ☺☺☺

Answer (score 0):

add .value to get Input email like this:

```
var testRe = re.test(inputEmail.value);
```

Comment: That solved the issue of it not following the if statement popping up the alert box. But it is not executing the else.